# Usage of Multiple JMS Connection Factory

Tags: spring-jms

I have written a JMS Listener class which will listen almost 100+ queues, once after processing, it sends back message to Response Queue again. Register this listener class for 100+ queues by programmatically using Spring JMS. In this scenario, as of now, I have used only one JMS Connection Factory had been used by the JMS Listener and JMS Template ( which is posting the message to response queue ). I could sense, using of one connection factory seems will impact the performance on message processing. Going with another JMS connection factory will make sense here?

Answer (score 0):

The key performance objective is to re-use JMS connections, and to some degree, JMS sessions.  Establishing JMS connections is relatively expensive.  For message listeners, if you are changing a message filter, then you will need to use a new message listener.  If you are just listening for a message on a destination, then you can reuse the message listener as well.

I would recommend using a caching/pooling connection factory and keeping your JMS connections nailed up.  After that, you can try to have Spring JMS also reuse your sessions.

Comment: I used this org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory  class, but this is just caching the sessions (producers/consumers/both) only, actually not caching the connection something like database connection pooling. Any other alternate solution for caching the connections in Spring?

Comment: I've always found that the `org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory` works well.  On github: https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms.  This is a project that moved the pool out of activemq.